# How to find and edit a value in nested (Array) document in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I looking for a solution. I create the following mongoDB documents dynamic...
in the next step i search for the right document with the _id of the conditions with..

```
Rule.findOne({ "condition._id": this.condition._id }).then((res) => {});
```

so far so good...Now i have the right document..
Next i want to find in these document the right condition (with the _id of the condition and edit one value of it... 
How can i tell mongo something like `updateOne({ "condition._id": this.condition._id },condition[indexOfcondtion].state = false})`...??

```
{
"_id": "5e79fb802a18950f15ab0f79",
"name": "te",
"description": "d",
"condition": [
    {
        "_id": "5e79fb872a18950f15ab0f7a",
        "moduleId": 1,
        "moduleType": 2,
        "uniqueID": 5
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e7e8012cc3ef20e441fe285",
        "state": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e7e8012cc3ef20e421fe577",
        "state": false
    }
],
"__v": 0,
"uniqueID": 1
```

}